# Parse Coefficients of Binomials c++

Tags: c++, scanf, binomial-coefficients

I am attempting to read in a list of binomials, separated by line in a file given as a command line argument. The file looks like this...

numbers.txt

```
2.1x+1
3x-5.3
-24.1x+24.7
0x-15.5
-12.3x+0
```

Expected output:

```
input: 2.1x+1
real: 2.1
imag: +1
input: 3x-5.3
real: 3
imag: -5.3
input: -24.1x+24.7
real: -24.1
imag: +24.7
input: 0x-15.5
real: 0
imag: -15.5
input: -12.3x+0
real: -12.3
imag: +0
```

My Output:

```
input: 2.1x+1
real: 2.1
imag: 2.07545e-317
input: 3x-5.3
real: 3
imag: 2.07545e-317
input: -24.1x+24.7
real: -24.1
imag: 2.07545e-317
input: 0x-15.5
real: -24.1
imag: 2.07545e-317
input: -12.3x+0
real: -12.3
imag: 2.07545e-317
```

I'm having with getting the 'real' double variable value correct. sscanf() is also not detecting the leading zero value for one of the x-Coefficients, is there something I can do to sscanf() to fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class binomial
{
public:
  double real;
  double imag;
  string usercmplx;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

  string word, input;
  vector <binomial> VecNums;
  binomial complexnum;

  // Inializes vector to size for speedup                                                                             
  VecNums.reserve(1000);

  ifstream file(argv[1]);

  // Parse txt file line by line                                                                                      
  while (file >> input) {
    // handle empty lines                                                                                             
    if (!input.empty()){

    // Saves the user input format                                                                                    
    complexnum.usercmplx = input;

    // This seperates the input into the real and imaginary parts                                                     
    sscanf(input.c_str(), "%lf %lf", &complexnum.real, &complexnum.imag);

    cout << "input: " << input << endl;
    cout << "real: " << complexnum.real << endl;
    cout << "imag: " <<complexnum.imag << endl;

    // Push binomials into Vector                                                                                       
    VecNums.push_back(complexnum);

    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sscanf(input.c_str(), "%lf %lf", &complexnum.real, &complexnum.imag);
```

This `sscanf` format string states: the input contains a `double` value, followed by some whitespace, followed by another `double` value.

You provide the following `input`:

```
 2.1x+1
```

Do you see here a `double` value, followed by some whitespace, and another `double` value? Of course not. The first `double` value is followed by the character 'x'. That's not whitespace.

Since the actual input does not match the expected input, `sscanf()` fails to parse the input and initialize the returned values. If you check the return value from `sscanf()`, you would know that.

One of the ways to fix this is to tell `sscanf()` that a character follows the double value.

```
char char_value;

sscanf(input.c_str(), "%lf%c%lf", &complexnum.real, &char_value, &complexnum.imag);
```

Comment: I see... the whitespace problem makes sense now. The problem with the leading zero before the char_value still occurs. Not understanding why

Comment: for `0x-15.5`, you need use `sscanf(str.c_str(), "%dx%lf", &real, &image);`. Note: `%d` not `%lf`. but i also want to know the reason.